# How can I make alarm events using React Native?

Tags: react-native, alarm

I was searching around the web, even in StackOverflow and I didn't find a way of making alarms that opens the app. Could anyone tell me if is there a way to do that natively and if it isn't, which library could I use for having a big control with alarms? I want to **open the app and then play a sound for waking up proposals**. Thanks!

PS: If you know a library that only works for Android, that's ok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a check on these libraries:

- [react-native-alarms](https://github.com/upvalue/react-native-alarms)
- [react-native-alarm-notification](https://github.com/emekalites/react-native-alarm-notification)
- [react-native-alarm](https://github.com/smartliang/react-native-alarm)

The last one support ios and android, the others only support android.