# How to create an alarm clock app with expo

Tags: react-native, expo, alarm

expo does not support an alarm clock. and I don't want to use third-party libraries, I want to try only with expo react native. How can I do?

Comment: You should try make a start on it and share an individual problem.  This is too broad of a question.

Comment: I just want a hint. Which api or component I've to use.

Comment: https://github.com/bartolomej/rn-alarm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183075/best-ways-to-implement-alarms-into-react-native
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519776/how-can-i-make-alarm-events-using-react-native